# Symfony2 Form partial update not remove data

Tags: php, forms, symfony

This issue is already mentioned here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10364

I'm facing this and can't find any solution.
I have 1 entity and using 2 separate forms for partial updating some specific fields. So I'm using `$form->submit()` with `clearMissing = false` for partial update. But if I have multiple checkbox fields (it's many to many relation), form doesn't remove unchecked data (checked data is added OK).

Is there any solutions for this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your Entity where you are talking about is the inverse side of the many-to-many relation?

([See this article](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association))